# Как улучшить производительность кода python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

```
for i in range(len(PI)-1):
    if PI.loc[i, TR] == PI.loc[i+1, TR]:
        PI.loc[i, 'DX'] = PI.loc[i+1, X] - PI.loc[i, X]
        PI.loc[i, 'DY'] = PI.loc[i+1, Y] - PI.loc[i, Y]
        PI.loc[i, 'DZ'] = PI.loc[i+1, Z] - PI.loc[i, Z]
    PI['PL'] = np.sqrt(pow(PI.DX, 2) + pow(PI.DY, 2) + pow(PI.DZ, 2))
```

Вот пример входных данных данных

```
TR,X,Y,Z
K-11,367019.7,867162.3,505.2
K-11,367019.2,867142.7,509.5
K-11,367018.6,867137.7,510.0
K-14,367313.4,867301.7,594.3
K-14,367312.2,867224.5,605.1
K-14,367312.7,867213.9,604.6
K-15,367166.1,867197.1,557.6
K-15,367165.6,867187.1,558.6
K-15,367165.9,867148.2,562.9
```

Comment: Приведите входные данные, чтобы любой желающий помочь сразу смог с ними работать, а не придумывать свое (ссылка `править` под вопросом)

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь функционалом pandas:

```
Ваш df:
     TR         X         Y      Z
0  K-11  367019.7  867162.3  505.2
1  K-11  367019.2  867142.7  509.5
2  K-11  367018.6  867137.7  510.0
3  K-14  367313.4  867301.7  594.3
4  K-14  367312.2  867224.5  605.1
5  K-14  367312.7  867213.9  604.6
6  K-15  367166.1  867197.1  557.6
7  K-15  367165.6  867187.1  558.6
8  K-15  367165.9  867148.2  562.9
```

ну и далее:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df["PL"] = df["TR"].eq(df["TR"].shift().bfill()).astype(int)
df["PL"] = np.where(df["PL"]==1, np.sqrt(pow(df["X"].diff().shift(-1), 2) +
                                         pow(df["Y"].diff().shift(-1), 2) + 
                                         pow(df["Z"].diff().shift(-1), 2)),
                    np.nan)
```

Получаем df:

```
     TR         X         Y      Z          PL
0  K-11  367019.7  867162.3  505.2   20.072369
1  K-11  367019.2  867142.7  509.5    5.060632
2  K-11  367018.6  867137.7  510.0  347.720477
3  K-14  367313.4  867301.7  594.3         NaN
4  K-14  367312.2  867224.5  605.1   10.623559
5  K-14  367312.7  867213.9  604.6  154.863811
6  K-15  367166.1  867197.1  557.6         NaN
7  K-15  367165.6  867187.1  558.6   39.138089
8  K-15  367165.9  867148.2  562.9         NaN
```

Результат, конечно, лучше перепроверить, потому как у меня не было на это времени.